# Managed analogue for SendMessage API function or How to send a message to window from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, windows-messages

I want to send a window message from one application (console) to the wondow of another application. I can use WinAPI functions SendMessage or PostMessage, but may be there is managed way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no managed alternative to that but you can easily P/Invoke with:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessage(this.Handle, COMMAND_HERE, PARAM_HERE, 0);
}
```